# Efficient decoding of the E8/Leech lattice

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices, quantization, discretization-and-quantization

**Background:**

Our goal is to quantize a sequence of floating point numbers generated i.i.d. from a standard Gaussian source and minimize the MSE reconstruction error. We can use two bits for each sample. Moreover, we need to decode efficiently on a GPU, so variable-length codes should be avoided since they are not very parallelizable. However, we can pool samples together, e.g. encode a vector in $\mathbb{R}^8$ with 16 bits.

Since it's a memoryless source, a natural idea is to quantize each sample with two bits. However, empirical experiments indicate that we can get a lower MSE by encoding blocks of 8 samples with the intersection of the E8 lattice and an L-2 ball of radius $\sqrt{10}$ around the origin (bonus question: why is it better than quantizing each sample separately?). The problem is how to decode the quantized samples efficiently, or more specifically, how to map the 16-bit pattern to a vector in E8. A straightforward idea is to use a codebook of size $2^{16} = 65536$. However, observe that all vectors in E8 have an even number of negative components, so we can store the sign for each component with 7 bits and calculate the last one through parity. For the remaining 9 bits, we only need a codebook of size $2^9 = 512$, each entry representing a vector in E8 with at most one negative component. The takeaway is that we can reduce the codebook size drastically by observing that the sign and absolute value are "independent".

**Question:**

Now we want to use the Leech lattice to encode blocks of 24 samples with 48 bits. This requires a codebook of size $2^{48 - 23} = 33554432$, which is way too large. How can we "partition" the bit pattern into independent bitsets and reduce the codebook size? There are some related questions (e.g. [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18568/leech-lattice-decomposition), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84586/implementation-of-the-bounded-distance-decoder-of-leech-lattice)), but I don't have a background in DSP or cryptography so it's unclear if that's what we are looking for.